# VSS is not getting the correct version for asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-sourcesafe

I am using VSS for my ASP.NET (VS 2008) project which is used by multiple users in multiple systems. It worked for first few days without any issue, but later it is showing some issues which are listed below.

1. Showing some files are already checked out, even if that user already checked in.
2. While getting latest, it is showing error like,

   File System4\VSS\data\popdaaa.a not found
3. At the end, showing error message like, 
   Get Version could not be completed.

My questions are

1. If it is the issue with VSS file corruption, then how can I fix the issue.
2. Is there any other Version controls (for free) to integrate on Visual Studio. I tried TortoiseSVN, but didn't find the options correctly for Visual Studio projects.
3. Should I delete the VSS folder and create once again. I did like for 3 times before, still the same issue.
4. Is there any known issues with VSS or the issue with our systems.

The VSS Version is 8.xx

Here are some issues generating when we analyse VSS

```
The project dialogs references a child whose physical file (DPDAAAAA) is missing or corrupted.
The project images references a child whose physical file (SPDAAAAA) is missing or corrupted.
The project tabletools references a child whose physical file (FRDAAAAA) is missing or corrupted.
The project img references a child whose physical file (ISDAAAAA) is missing or corrupted.
The project forms references a child whose physical file (TPDAAAAA) is missing or corrupted.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running Analyze and Fix VSS DB (it should be in the same directory as Source Safe).

FWIW:  I've never liked integrating Source Control with Visual Studio.  Having Source Control independent gives us more explicit control and reduces 'surprises'.

Comment: My free advise:  Back up everything all the time.  And store some copies off site.